# iOS Sharepoint App login error

Tags: ios, sharepoint, request, asihttprequest

i´m developing an iOS iPad App to connect to a Sharepoint. I´m doing this with the ASIHTTPRequest Framework. My code looks like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://SHAREPOINTURL"];

NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
"<soap12:Body>\n"
"<GetListCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\" />\n"
"</soap12:Body>\n"
"</soap12:Envelope>\n";

asiRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[asiRequest setUsername:@"USERNAME"];
[asiRequest setPassword:@"PASSWORD"];

[asiRequest setDelegate:self];
[asiRequest appendPostData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

So far, so good, but when I debug this, I get an 403 FORBIDDEN Error. Why?
In my opinion, I don´t think the mistakes are the Username and Password. Maybe there is something wrong with the Request?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your url, I have to ask, are you POSTing to `_vti_bin/authentication.asmx`?

If you already are, I can only suggest this as I don't know if ASI puts the login info in correctly.  Try putting it in your SOAP message manually like this:  (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd923689%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>PASSWORD</password>
    </Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This should return the login cookie you need to use the rest of the web services.

EDIT: One more thing, you need to set your SP server to use forms authentication rather than NTLM authentication (which is the default).

Comment: Hmm.. there must be a mistake. The only think the Server returned idt this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your SOAP envelope and the error message I think you are missing the `SOAPAction` header in your request.

The code below show an example of how to create a request for getting all lists in a Sharepoint instance. I am using AFNetworking and some parts might not be applicable for the ASIHTTPRequest framework.

```
...

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                  path:@"_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
                                            parameters:nil];

NSString *soapEnvelope = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
  @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
  @"<soap:Body>"
  @"<GetListCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\" />"
  @"</soap:Body>"
  @"</soap:Envelope>";

// Set headers
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

// Content length
NSString *contentLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", soapEnvelope.length];
[request setValue:contentLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// Set body
[request setHTTPBody:[soapEnvelope dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

...
```

But as Tim say, you must the authenticated before you can use this method.

There are several authentication mechanism, Forms claims as described above by Tim or NTLM (and some other). You must check how your Sharepoint instance is configured, or possibly support several mechanisms if you can not control the configuration of the server.